# Apt-get issues removing redmine from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, apt, 16.04, redmine

```
yugasalabs-26@yugasalabs-26:~$ sudo apt-get remove redmine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-coffeescript libjs-jquery-ui libuv1 nodejs redmine-sqlite
  ruby-actionmailer ruby-actionpack ruby-actionpack-action-caching
  ruby-actionpack-xml-parser ruby-actionview ruby-activejob ruby-activemodel
  ruby-activerecord ruby-activesupport ruby-addressable ruby-arel ruby-atomic
  ruby-awesome-nested-set ruby-binding-of-caller ruby-blankslate ruby-builder
  ruby-byebug ruby-coderay ruby-coffee-rails ruby-coffee-script
  ruby-coffee-script-source ruby-columnize ruby-css-parser
  ruby-debug-inspector ruby-erubis ruby-execjs ruby-ffi ruby-globalid
  ruby-hike ruby-hmac ruby-htmlentities ruby-i18n ruby-jbuilder
  ruby-jquery-rails ruby-json ruby-listen ruby-loofah ruby-mail
  ruby-mime-types ruby-multi-json ruby-net-ldap ruby-nokogiri ruby-oj
  ruby-openid ruby-polyglot ruby-protected-attributes ruby-rack
  ruby-rack-openid ruby-rack-test ruby-rails ruby-rails-deprecated-sanitizer
  ruby-rails-dom-testing ruby-rails-html-sanitizer ruby-rails-observers
  ruby-railties ruby-rb-inotify ruby-rbpdf ruby-rbpdf-font ruby-redcarpet
  ruby-request-store ruby-rmagick ruby-roadie ruby-roadie-rails ruby-sass
  ruby-sass-rails ruby-sdoc ruby-spring ruby-sprockets ruby-sprockets-rails
  ruby-sqlite3 ruby-thread-safe ruby-tilt ruby-treetop ruby-turbolinks
  ruby-tzinfo ruby-uglifier ruby-web-console
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  redmine
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 9,094 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package redmine (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redmine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
yugasalabs-26@yugasalabs-26:~$
```

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package redmine (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal` - did you try this suggestion?

Comment: Yes I tried again what exactly I done previously for installing redmine on ubuntu-16.04 Here current error:

Comment: dpkg: error processing package redmine (--configure):
 package redmine is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in "gimp". If you had changed the symbolic link of python (/usr/bin/python), it would be a factor. My problem was fixed by reverting this change.